# Error: validateDOMNesting(…): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>, Using AniLink inside AniLink

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am using this code snippet in a Gatsby project, It seems using AniLink inside another AniLink is not allowed, but I can not figure out the solution:

```
import React from 'react'
import AniLink from "gatsby-plugin-transition-link/AniLink";
const titleStyle = {
    fontWeight: "700",
}
const authorLinkStyle = {
    color: "#00BCD4"
}
const Author = ({ children, to }) => (
    <AniLink style={authorLinkStyle} to={to} className="font-weight-bold" fade>
        {children}
    </AniLink>
)
const Card = ({ title, description, timeStamp, authorName, slug }) => {
    const cardTextColor = typeof window !== "undefined" && getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--card-text-color")
    const cardLinkStyle = { color: cardTextColor, textDecoration: "none" }
    return (
        <AniLink
            style={cardLinkStyle}
            to={slug}
            cover
            bg="#00BCD4"
        >
            <div className="card my-4" >
                <div className="card-body" >
                    <h5 className="card-title" style={titleStyle}>{title}</h5>
                    <p className="card-text">{description}</p>
                    <h6 className="card-subtitle text-muted">
                        <Author to="/about">{authorName}</Author> on {timeStamp}
                    </h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </AniLink>)
}
export default Card
```

I think errors happen from this line:

```
<Author to="/about">{authorName}</Author> on {timeStamp}
```

The error in F12:
[image]

Have anyone using AniLink and see this error?
Any suggestion would be great..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically you spotted the mistake. You are wrapping a component (`AniLink`, which is an anchor, `<a>`) inside another anchor (`Author` component).

This, when compiled and transpiled into the output HTML, is creating an invalid structure of an anchor as a descendant of another anchor (`<a><a>Link</a></a>`). Is not an issue of `AniLink` nor React or Gatsby, is an issue of your component's structure.

The solution is simple, don't wrap it. You may want to do the something like:

```
<div className="card my-4" >
    <div className="card-body" >
      <AniLink
          style={cardLinkStyle}
          to={slug}
          cover
          bg="#00BCD4"
        >
        <h5 className="card-title" style={titleStyle}>{title}</h5>
        <p className="card-text">{description}</p>
       </AniLink>
        <h6 className="card-subtitle text-muted">
            <Author to="/about">{authorName}</Author> on {timeStamp}
        </h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

The snippet above won't create the error but you may need to tweak the layout to fit your specifications and design.

Comment: Perfect! Now it works, thank you so much!